# Installing Solr in a XAMPP server in a LINUX server

Tags: php, linux, solr, xampp, pecl

I try to install Solr PHP extension to my webserver. I already have an XAMPP server and I'm using PECL to install solr

`$ cd /opt/lampp/bin`

`$ sudo ./pecl install solr-1.0.1`

But I got the following error:

```
checking libxml2 install dir... /usr/lib
checking for xml2-config path...
configure: error: xml2-config not found. Please check your libxml2 installation.
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/solr/configure --enable-solr=yes --enable-solr-debug=no --with-curl=
/usr --with-libxml-dir=/usr/lib' failed
```

During the installation it prompts me to input a path:

`libxml2 install prefix [/usr] :`

I have tried with `enter` and the `/usr/lib`

What shall I input there to not get an error? Or how shall I install to not get an error?

---

Now I have libxml2 installed through `yum install libxml2-devel`. But I got some wierd errors now. Here are just a few of them, it ends with:

```
no such parameter
/tmp/pear/temp/solr/solr_types.h:388: error: declaration for parameter 'client_count' but no such parameter
/tmp/pear/temp/solr/solr_types.h:386: error: declaration for parameter 'document_count' but no such parameter 
/tmp/pear/temp/solr/solr_types.h:384: error: declaration for parameter 'request_count' but no such parameter 
/tmp/pear/temp/solr/php_solr.c:1185: error: expected '{' at end of input
make: *** [php_solr.lo] Error 1 ERROR: `make' failed
```

Comment: I think this question is for serverfault.com (or maybe http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This is a question about installing a PHP PECL extension, it's not specifically a unix config question. Questions about installing development tools and libs are on-topic here. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have libxml2 installed? Where is it installed? Do you have it configured?; Which system are you using, probably you can install it via your systems package manager? If not, why not?

Comment: Now I have libxml2 installed through `yum install libxml2-devel`. But I got some wierd errors now? There are errors yeverwhere when it tries to install solr PHP extension. Btw I'm using Amazon free tiers so I use their linux version.

Comment: Here are just a few of them. it ends with: \n

no such parameter
/tmp/pear/temp/solr/solr_types.h:388: error: declaration for parameter 'client_count' but n
o such parameter
/tmp/pear/temp/solr/solr_types.h:386: error: declaration for parameter 'document_count' but
 no such parameter
/tmp/pear/temp/solr/solr_types.h:384: error: declaration for parameter 'request_count' but 
no such parameter
/tmp/pear/temp/solr/php_solr.c:1185: error: expected '{' at end of input
make: *** [php_solr.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed

Comment: The code you have downloaded from PECL does not compile on your machine. Which PHP version are you using?

Comment: According to `phpinfo()` I have the version `5.3.1`

Comment: And I solr Only need "PHP version 5.2.11 or later is required"

Comment: Which PEAR version do you have?

Comment: How Do I check that? It dont show up in php info.

Comment: `$ pecl version` - I've edited your question and put the part about the libxml2-devel install in there. Can you review if the error output is correct?

Comment: ok version `1.9.0`and yes the question is correct

Comment: @hakre Why can't I manually compile it? I tried to cd in to /tmp/pear/downloads/solr-1.0.1 and type in the command line ./configure but nothing happens? Also tried make

Comment: I've seen you type `./pecl` - just to ensure: Have you installed `php5-devel` on that machine? If so, there should be a system-wide `pecl` command. Please clarify, not that we're looking at the wrong end.

Comment: I have run `$ sudo yum install php-devel` if it thats what you mean

Comment: But I dont think I have php5-devel yet How do I Install it?

Comment: I cant use the pecl command system wide

Answer (score 2):

If you're using RHEL/Fedora/CentOS/Scientific linux then you need to install libxml2-devel

```
 yum install libxml2-devel
```

Comment: I tried this and it installed libxml2. But I got some new errors. Check my question above

Answer (score 1):

I could easily install [PECL Solr](http://pecl.php.net/package/solr) via my systems package manager, probably this works for you as well. I found it very easy so probably worth to share (Fedora 14):

```
$ sudo yum install php-pecl-solr
```

A little later I got `php-pecl-solr-0.9.11-1.fc14.x86_64` installed, [the package's fedora homepage is here](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/updates/php-pecl-solr).

---

I could locate the libxml2 version with this command:

```
$ locate libxml2.so
```

probably this is helpful as well.

Comment: It just says no package available

Comment: Please tell your OS and version. Looks like you have yum available at least, probably it's easy to add the missing repository.

Comment: I'm using Amazon free tiers so I use their linux version.

Answer (score 0):

Some useful links:

> http://projects.mediashelf.us/projects/8/wiki/Setting_up_Fedora_and_Solr_for_use_with_ActiveFedora#Install-Solr
>
> http://oxfordrepo.blogspot.com/2008/01/populating-search-engine-apache-solr.html