# Solr PHP extension is not working after manual installation?

Tags: php, linux, xampp, lampp

I have successfully compiled Solr PHP extension It took me a whole day :S. I have compiled the code and also copied the solr.so extension file to `/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions`. I also edited my `php.ini` file and created a new file called `solr.ini` in `/etc/php.d` folder. I basically followed most of the steps according to this link http://www.gosquared.com/liquidicity/archives/836.

Now I check ed with `$ php -m`to see if Solr PHP extensions was succesfully installed. It appeared so. And then I tried to use its functions. None of them works. What have I missed?

Please help me! This have been really baking my nuts!

EDIT:

I have also restarted my lampp server, so that is not the case

Comment: What you say "none of them works" can you expand? Do you get errors?

Comment: yes they are undefined, Do you know what I have been missed?

Comment: @Kev Do you know how I can debug this?

Comment: Related question on how to install the solr extension is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322165/installing-solr-in-a-xampp-server-in-a-linux-server

Answer (score 0):

The CLI PHP executable, i.e., the one you're running with `php -m` is using a different php.ini file than the web server.

You can check which files are being loaded by the cli with `php --ini`; for the web server, create a script with the content `<?php phpinfo();` and check the configuration section.